# Django Admin Panel URL GO WRONG

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a document file from the admin panel Django but I am getting 404 not found URL errors.

admin file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Document
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Document)
```

```
from django.db import models
class Document(models.Model):
    
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_file = models.FileField(upload_to='docs')
    doc_price = models.IntegerField()
    doc_cat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_desc = models.TextField()
    doc_var = models.TextField()
```

Main URLs

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('UserAccount.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('Dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What could possibly be the error?

Comment: there is no any error in your code which you have posted. 
There might be error in ``urls.py`` 
some error log might be shown in your terminal or browser. 
so can you post that

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://lawbrief.org/admin/Dashboard/documents/add/
Raised by: django.contrib.admin.options.add_view

Comment: The url you mentioned ( lawbrief.org/admin/Dashboard/documents/add ) definitely does not look like a URL from Django Admin, judging by the uppercase "D" in "Dashboard". Where do you get that url?

Answer (score 0):

404 error means that path to the admin panel doesn't declarated.

Check main urls.py file. There should be this import statement: `from django.contrib import admin` and `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` line in `urlpatterns` var.

Comment: I have that added already. I was able to add a category from the admin panel. but I can't add the document.

Comment: Check if you have ```'django.contrib.admin',``` in ```installed_apps``` in your project settings file